# How listen update event for redis with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I'm using redis for caching data with spring boot. I have sucessfully defined method to store data in cache and now I would like to define a method to send a Flux (dependency webflux) of java object (let's call it Data) when the cached value which is associated to a key is updated.

I've been trying to set this up for 1 day now.

Comment: In short, are you looking for an update when your key changes?

Comment: Hi @AnkitSahay, I want to send a message to clients when my cache is updated not the key. For example I store v1 value in cache opsForValue().set(key, v1) and I would to send v2 value when I do opsForValue().set(key, v2)

Comment: It’s still not very clear. Would suggest you to add more details or example scenario in the question itself. What I am understanding is, when the value for a key changes, you want to notify your client that the key has changed